# Simple explanation of Dijkstra's Algorithm?

Tags: graph-theory

Can anyone provide a simple explanation of Dijkstra's Algorithm?

My text, discrete mathematics with applications by Susanna Epp provides a very complex explanation of the algorithm that I cannot seem to decipher:

[image]

I want to use the algorithm in order to solve this Review Question we have for our final:

[image]

Comment: Would that help? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dijkstra%27s_algorithm#Description

Comment: Ah, thanks I think that will help a bit!  And the pseudocode below it will definitely help.

Answer (score 3):

The best way to get a "feel" for the algorithm, is to see it in action on several simple examples. (At least in my opinion.)

The best way I know how to do this is the following webpage:

**EDIT:** The page is now available in English:
https://www-m9.ma.tum.de/graph-algorithms/spp-dijkstra/index_en.html

(Thank you to the person who pointed this out to me.)

<strike>https://www-m9.ma.tum.de/graph-algorithms/spp-dijkstra/index_de.html</strike>

The only problem is that it is in German, so you might need to use Google Translate on it. I will try to describe to you the steps you need to use it:

Click "Fertig! Weiter zum Algorithmus"  (Ready! On to the algorithm!)

Then click on one of the nodes 
("Wähle zuerst einen Startknoten aus!" "First choose a start node!")

Then click "Nächster Schritt" (Next step) until the algorithm terminates.

You can also use it on different graphs besides the example first offered on the page; if you need clarifications on the translation let me know.

Comment: That looks amazing honestly!  I just wish there was a version in English instead of Google having to translate for me.  Still, the translation seems to be strangely accurate when discussing the steps so I am going to continue to try to use it.

Comment: Yeah TUM is a pretty international university, so I'm also surprised there isn't an English version. Again, let me know if there is something you need translated that google messed up.

Comment: I will do that.  Thanks for taking time out of your day to help a stranger online! :)

Comment: may want to look at: https://www.cs.usfca.edu/~galles/visualization/Dijkstra.html or http://weierstrass.is.tokushima-u.ac.jp/ikeda/suuri/dijkstra/Dijkstra.shtml (same idea for visualization, but in English).